# Hibernate, select only parent class columns from a single table shared between parent and child class

Tags: mysql, hibernate, web, hql, java-ee-7

Hibernate: I have a need to select only parent object from a single db table which are mapped to both parent class and child class in hibernate.

This is the simplified hibernate table definition:

```
@Entity
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType. SINGLE_TABLE)
public class parent{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="parent_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="parent_gen", sequenceName="PARENT_SEQUENCE")
    private int parentID;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "childtable")
public class child extends parent{
 @Column(name="favoriteColor")
    private String favoriteColor;
}
```

and in mysql database, this is "childtable" looks like:

```
|id|name|favoriteColor|
|1|John|blue|
|2|Smith|red|
|3|Gary|yellow|
```

Now, I want to select from childtable with parent columns only and expect to obtain parent object in hql.

something like:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Query query = session
                .createQuery("from parent where id <4");
         List<parent> result = query.list();
```

I have not introduced a DTYPE to childtable as there will be no instance where I need to insert parent class to childtable. I only want to differentiate parent and child object when doing select query.

How can I make it work with hibernate?

**Update 1:**
I have find a way to get around the problem by running this. I am not sure if this is the correct way of solving the problem, but it works.

```
Query query = session
                    .createQuery("select new parent(id,name) from parent where id <4");
             List<parent> result = query.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have find a way to get around the problem by running this. I am not sure if this is the correct way of solving the problem, but it works.

```
Query query = session
                .createQuery("select new parent(id,name) from parent where id <4");
         List<parent> result = query.list();
```